# How do I get this Twig variable to print inside the inline style attribute?

Tags: twig

In a Twig template, I have a variable (color) that I'm trying to print inside an inline style attribute, but am confused on how to properly do this.

I've tried:

```
<div class="field_body" style="color: {{ color }} !important;">
```

and

```
{{ '<div class="field_body" style="color: ' ~ color ' !important;">' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example miss a string concat operator (~), as example:

```
{{ ('<div class="field_body" style="color:' ~ color|default('black') ~ ' !important;">') | raw }}
```

If the variable doesn't not exists you can specify a fallback with the default twig filter.

You can verify in this working [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/3lcpup).

Hope this help

Comment: Found out my variable was an array, so that's why it wasn't working right for me. Thanks!